# Does sequelize allow to start a field name start with number using PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've existing database and I cannot change my field name. On 3rdpty_ordering, I'm having error that keyword cannot be be set as integer in Sequelize. Can anyone help me with this issue is there any other way to solve this problem. THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Tutorial = sequelize.define("project_quickbase", {
      project_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      3rdpty_ordering: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      
    });
    return Tutorial;
  };
```

Comment: AFAIK field names shouldn't start with digits

Comment: SQL doesn't allow column names that start with a number unless it's quoted using double quotes - which is highly discouraged. So better find a different column name.